# Assigning to multiple variables fails for even number of variables

Tags: vb6, variable-assignment

I'm working on an old legacy project written in VB6, and one section of code involves iterating a loop to compute some counts. I just had to add one more count to the loop. The code starts off like this:

```
Dim a%, b%, c%, d%
a% = b% = c% = d% = 0   ' initialise counters
```

One of the counts ends up off by one and it turns out it's because in the above code `a%` is set to -1 while all the other variables are set to 0. This only seems to happen when there is an even number of variables. The following [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hVRoXt) reproduces the issue:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim a%, b%, c%, d%, e%, f%      
    
    a% = b% = 0     
    Console.WriteLine(CStr(a%) + " " + CStr(b%))
    ' Outputs -1 0
    
    a% = b% = c% = 0
    Console.WriteLine(CStr(a%) + " " + CStr(b%) + " " + CStr(c%))       
    ' Outputs 0 0 0
    
    a% = b% = c% = d% = 0       
    Console.WriteLine(CStr(a%) + " " + CStr(b%) + " " + CStr(c%) + " " + CStr(d%))      
    ' Outputs -1 0 0 0
            
    a% = b% = c% = d% = e% = 0      
    Console.WriteLine(CStr(a%) + " " + CStr(b%) + " " + CStr(c%) + " " + CStr(d%) + " " + CStr(e%))     
    ' Outputs 0 0 0 0 0
    
    a% = b% = c% = d% = e% = f% = 0     
    Console.WriteLine(CStr(a%) + " " + CStr(b%) + " " + CStr(c%) + " " + CStr(d%) + " " + CStr(e%) + " " + CStr(f%))        
    ' Outputs -1 0 0 0 0 0
    
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

It's easy enough to fix the bug, just assign all the variables to zero individually, but my question is why does this happen, and in particular why only for an even number of variables?

Comment: I've never initiated multiple variables like that, always doing them individually in the past, but is it possible that VB is setting c% to the result of d% = 0 (which will be True as variables are initialised to zero when they are created) and doing the same back along the line to a%? (True in VB6 = -1 and False = 0.)

Comment: Ok. That should be forward along the line, but you get the idea!

Comment: If `a% = b% = c% = 0` parses as `%a = (b% = (c% = 0))` then `c% = 0` evaluates to true (-1) at which point `b% = (c% = 0)` evaluates to false (0). This `0` is then assigned to `a%`. This is the only assignment. The values printed for `%b%` and `%c` are their default values.

Comment: If you replace all of the 0s by `-1` (so `a% = b% = -1`, etc.) then you get the same sort of output, but now with `a% = -1` occurring when there are an odd number of variables. This adds evidence to the hypothesis of that there is only 1 assignment happening and that all the other equal signs are comparisons that are alternating between true and false.

Comment: @JohnColeman yes and if you assign other values to the variables other than a% they don't get set to zero by the assignment. I think your explanation is correct, if you add as an answer I will accept it otherwise I can self-answer.

Comment: Are you sure this is VB6? Because there is no `Console` in VB6, and assignments cannot be chained like this because an assignment doesn't return a value. VB.NET does have a `Console`, and assignments do return the assigned value...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yeah the fiddle isn't VB6 because I couldn't find a VB6 fiddle, but the same behaviour occurs in VB6. The version I'm using is Retail 6.0.9782. You're right that assignments can't be chained like that - that's what I've now found out. However it doesn't generate a compile error, so it's valid VB6 code, it just doesn't do what I expected.

Comment: It's legal, but it needs to be read and interpreted left-to-right: B=C (both 0) evaluates to true/-1, then -1=D is false/0, 0=E is true/-1, -1=F is false/0. Basically it's a bunch of implicit Boolean to numeric conversions, and the = operators (other than the first one) are _comparison_ operators. In other words I'd be surprised it does what it intends to be doing.

Comment: @JohnColeman you should just add a real answer

Comment: This variable assignment behavior is also documented in the vb6/vba docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa242760(v=vs.60)

Comment: Your variables are already zero. Basic assigns storage space and zeros the memory. In C the compiler only allocates memory, which may be any value, meaning the programmer must zero the memory.